# Is it best to use JavaScript or XQuery?

Tags: javascript, xquery

I learnt some Xquery (basics)

For example this :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>   
    <script type="application/xquery">
      declare sequential function local:set($loc, $evt) {
        b:setStyle(b:dom()//body, "background-color", $loc/@value)
      };
      
      for $button in b:dom()//input[@type="button"]
      return
      b:addEventListener($button, "onclick", local:set#2)
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Change the background color</h1>
    <input type="button" value="Blue"/>
    <input type="button" value="Red"/>
    <input type="button" value="Green"/>
    <br/>
    <input type="button" value="Black"/>
    <input type="button" value="White"/>
    <input type="button" value="Yellow"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

This changes the color on click. Now, how does coding in x-query compare with JS? Can X-query be used instead of javascript completely? Which one gives more control over the elements?

And am I wasting my time learning XQuery? I am asking this because almost everyone talks only about JavaScript. Is it viable to use XQuery in lieu of JS? And how do they compare in terms of browser support?

Comment: I`ll say to go with js because not many know xQuery, lets say that u make the project using xQuery and after a year someone else has to update it, he will suffer a lot...

Comment: Clicking the buttons actually does *not* change the background color (with Chrome and IE11)

Answer (score 2):

With javascript you could do it similarely, like in this example.

(i have to say, for me your test doesn't really work inside the snippet editor)

You should recognise the code structure quite easily, it doesn't really change this much. One function to set the color, on function that attaches the setColor function with the onclick event, and a query to get your items on which you want to set the event handler.

```js
function setColor() {
  document.body.style.background = this.value;
}

function onLoad() {
  var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input'),
    i, len, item;

  for (i = 0, len = input.length; i < len; i++) {
    item = input[i];
    if (item.getAttribute('type') === 'button') {
      item.addEventListener('click', setColor.bind(item));
    }
  }
}

window.onload = onLoad;
```

```html
<h1>Change the background color</h1>
<input type="button" value="Blue" />
<input type="button" value="Red" />
<input type="button" value="Green" />
<br/>
<input type="button" value="Black" />
<input type="button" value="White" />
<input type="button" value="Yellow" />
```

In JQuery it is even easier, there you could just do it like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('input[type=button]').on('click', function(e) {
    $(document.body).css('background', e.currentTarget.value);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Change the background color</h1>
<input type="button" value="Blue" />
<input type="button" value="Red" />
<input type="button" value="Green" />
<br/>
<input type="button" value="Black" />
<input type="button" value="White" />
<input type="button" value="Yellow" />
```

I would say using Javascript makes more sense. There are lots of frameworks out there, lots of people already tried stuff that you will most likely try and so if you get stuck or have questions, you would have a lot more resources to look into to find solutions to your problems.